# Bokeh Arrow cut off in plot

Tags: python, bokeh

I am developing something with bokeh where I want to create and modify some graphs depending on the postion and values of arrows in the plot. The lines are updated perfectly but I have some trouble with the arrows.

The problem is when a button creates an arrow in the plot it is cut off. This just happens when I use `row` in the `layout`

Here is a minimal example with an image of the plot

```py
    from bokeh.application import Application
    from bokeh.server.server import Server
    from bokeh.application.handlers.function import FunctionHandler
    from bokeh.layouts import layout,row
    from bokeh.models import Arrow, NormalHead,Button
    from bokeh.plotting import figure 
    from functools import partial

    class BkApp():
        def __init__(self):
            self.plot = figure(plot_height=200, plot_width=600, x_range=(-1,5), y_range=(-1500, 1500),tools='save')
            self.btn = Button(label="Create Arrow", button_type="success")
            self.doc = None
            self.Layout = layout()


    def Btn_function(APP:BkApp):
        APP.plot.add_layout(Arrow(end=NormalHead(size=5, fill_color="#C0392B"),
                           x_start=5,
                           y_start=0,
                           x_end=-1,
                           y_end=0,
                           line_width= 3,
                           line_color = "#C0392B"))
        APP.doc.clear()
        APP.doc.add_root(APP.Layout)

    def make_document(doc, APP:BkApp):
        APP.doc = doc
        APP.Layout = layout(row(APP.btn,APP.plot))
        APP.doc.add_root(APP.Layout)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = BkApp()
        app.btn.on_click(partial(Btn_function, APP=app))
        bkapp = {'/': Application(FunctionHandler(partial(make_document, APP=app)))}
        server = Server(bkapp)
        server.start()
        server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
        server.io_loop.start()
```

The arrow is cut off like this: 
[Cut off Arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epo5U.png)

But if I create the layout with any tool it works perfectly. So if I use this `APP.Layout = layout(APP.btn,APP.plot)` the plot shows the arrow.

I try to find a workaround but I don't understand why this error occurs just when I use `row`

I use Python 3.6 and bokeh 2.0.0

UPDATE: Apperently this only happens when I put the buttons left to the plot. If the buttons are on the right side everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're hitting this Bokeh issue: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9522